# IPython Cell Magic to Run this Cell in Client and in All Engines

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-parallel, ipython-magic

In IPython for parallel execution we have multiple engines.
The jobs are dispatched to them using: `%%px` cell magics to set up the environment in the clients and then using  `DirectView map_sync` to run the various experiments.

The experiments return a named-tuple of results.
Thus this named-tuple need to be declared in both the client and in each engine.

Currently each time I run it, I run it twice, one with `%%px` and once without.

is there a flag of `%%px` that will make it run both locally and in each engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of IPython 1.0, you can instruct %%px to also execute the cell locally.
This is done using the "--local" flag.

%%px --local

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Parallel%20Computing/Parallel%20Magics.ipynb

Comment: great first post. Welcome to StackOverflow.